# R - Converting and joining integer and numeric variables

Tags: r, join, type-conversion, data-conversion

I have a problem with a join in R, I've tried to create a reproducible example, but every one I've created works as intended, and I have no idea what the problem is to recreate. The dput is too large to provide as a whole, is there a way I can attach a file?

It is a problem with joining on different data types, integer and numeric. Most of the join happens as expected, but some does not join. This was eventually solved by exporting the data to Excel, changing the offending numeric variable to the "Number" format with no decimal places, saving and importing back in to R, where it is now an integer.

Is there an R equivalent of this step? as.integer() or as.numeric() did not provide the same result as opening in Excel and converting.

Comment: You could paste it with `dput(head(your_df))` .

Comment: There are `floor`, `ceiling` and `truncate` type functions that can be used in addition to perhaps `as.integer` to get the numbers into the right place. Try doing `?floor` in R and you will see other functions and documentation.

Comment: Joins can fail on numeric types due to decimal representation rounding off problems.

Comment: and they can fail if the integers are actually factors...use str(df) to see what is happening in there.

Comment: if you are importing using `read.table()` or similar be sure to set stringsasfactors = FALSE, to begin with. your integers may be factors, character, or numeric all dependent on the data source and method of importing.

Comment: All of these are good tips. It turned out to be a mismatch due to whitespace, which can be solved through read.csv(..., strip.white = TRUE).